# Is closing fstream ( I/O ) necessary?

Tags: c++

I was learning about fstream, ofstream, and ifstream.
This work as expected
Here's the code:

```
    myFile.open("brod.txt");
    myFile << "Item 1";
    myFile.close();

    myFile.open("brod1.txt");
    myFile << "Item 1";
    myFile.close();
```

[image]

but if I remove the `myFile.close()` and change the output string.

[image]

The second notepad (brod1) doesn't change the text inside. There's an article that said the closing is not necessary since it will close itself. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Ok, I understand now, but why can't brod1 overwrite itself? since it opens another file at the same time

Comment: It's better to add a status check after `open`, we should not assume that it is success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `std::fstream` will close itself when it goes out of scope.

In your case however, the second call to `std::fstream::open()` *fails*, which sets the `failbit` on the stream (and *could* thrown an exception, but obviously doesn't in this case).  With the `failbit` set, additional attempts to write to that stream will fail.  See Return Value section here:  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/open/